# How to use collection types in model class as javafx.beans.property

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I've been writing my first javafx app. There are several model classes. I've describe entity classes as usual. F.e:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters bellow.....
}
```

I came across one [article](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) where the author advised to use Properties for all fields of a model class. F.e.:

```
public class NewPerson {

private final StringProperty firstName;
private final StringProperty lastName;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName.get();
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName.set(firstName);
}

public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName.get();
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName.set(lastName);
}

public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    return lastName;
} }
```

This works well! But how can I use java.util.Collections with Properties way? How should I "wrap" them? F.e. I wanna to use:

```
// set of user's certificates
private Set<Certificate> certificates;
```

How would it be as a property in NewPerson class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`SetProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SetProperty.html) like this:

```
// set of user's certificates
private SetProperty<Certificate> certificates;
```

Then, you can set the values using an [`ObservableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html). You can construct an `ObservableSet` with the help of [`FXCollections.observableSet(E... elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableSet-E...-).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want the API to look like. The simplest version is:

```
public class User {

    private final ObservableSet<Certificate> certificates = FXCollections.observableSet();

    public ObservableSet<Certificate> getCertificates() {
        return certificates ;
    }

    // other properties...
}
```

This allows quite a lot of functionality:

```
User user = new User();

user.getCertificates().addListener((SetChangeListener.Change<? extends Certificate> change) -> {
    if (change.wasAdded()) {
        // ...
    }
    if (change.wasRemoved()) {
        // ...
    }
});

Set<Certificate> someCertificates = ... ;
user.getCertificates().setAll(someCertificates);
user.getCertificates().add(new Certificate());

ObservableSet<Certificate> anotherSet = ... ;
Bindings.bindContent(user.getCertificates(), anotherSet);
// etc...
```

The only thing this doesn't allow is for you to externally plug in your own set implementation. I.e. you can't do

```
User user = new User();
ObservableSet<Certificate> certificates = ... ;
user.setCertificates(certificates);
```

Note that this is only really different from

```
user.getCertificates().setAll(certificates);
```

if you either had a specific implementation of `ObservableSet` that you wanted to use, or if you have a model class already containing an `ObservableSet<Certificate>` (and in the latter case, you could still consider `Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(user.getCertificates(), certificates)`). If you really need the `setCertificates(...)` API, then create a `SetProperty<Certificate>`:

```
public class User {

    private final SetProperty<Certificate> certificates 
        = new SimpleSetProperty<>(FXCollections.observableSet());

    public final ObservableSet<Certificate> getCertificates() {
        return certificatesProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCertificate(ObservableSet<Certificate> certificates) {
        certificatesProperty().set(certificates);
    }

    public SetProperty<Certificate> certificatesProperty() {
        return certificates ;
    }

    // other properties....
}
```

Comment: James_D, can you tell me, how to map this SetProperty into DB using Hibernate?

Comment: That's really a different question, and not at all easy to do. When you use Hibernate's collection mappings, Hibernate expects to be able to inject and retrieve its own special implementations of the collection interfaces (which is a vile restriction, but we have to live with it). This makes it hard (or impossible) to use subinterfaces of collection types, such as `ObservableSet`. I haven't found a good solution for this problem, other than having different classes for the database entity and the JavaFX model (effectively using a DTO layer).

Comment: James_D, I've been searching all working day for the solution and decided not to mix entity classes (for  Hib mapping) and classes with store state of View (you named them as JavaFX model). It seems to use MVVM pattern to build my app. I've searched for good examples, but found only 2-3 of them in the Internet. I would be extremely pleased, if you gave me efficient examples describe MVVM using JavaFX)